# Set drop location for certified-update

Tags: ruby, openssl, kramdown

When I run kramdown-rfc2629 (a Ruby gem), it gives me this warning:

> ** Configuration problem with OpenSSL certificate store at /usr/lib/ssl/cert.pem.
>
> **   Activating workaround.  Occasionally run `certified-update`.

However, running `certified-update` doesn't actually fix this warning.  From the warning code, it's checking for the existence of `OpenSSL::X509::DEFAULT_CERT_FILE`.  However, certified appears to be doing this to decide where to drop the file: `cert_path = Pathname.new File.expand_path('../../certs', __FILE__)` and `File.open(cert_path + 'ca-bundle.crt', 'w+')`.

`which certified-update` leads me to a Ruby helper script that asks Gem where the .rb file actually lives and launches it, but I'm not sure how to get it to tell me.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in `kramdown-rfc2629`: https://github.com/cabo/kramdown-rfc2629/issues/48. It may also be a bug in `certified`, which you should file at https://github.com/stevegraham/certified/issues if you need that package fixed.